# can i use c++ compiler to compile c source code?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler)

Just curious whether I could make use of a c++ compiler to compile c source code??Anyway is there any compiler that fully support c99 standard yet??

Comment: Two questions, two answers.  Sometimes.  Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517 (for the "any c99 compiler" part, yes - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

Answer (score 10):

C++ is *not* a superset of C. There are places where they differ, which means some C code will not compile in C++ mode.

As for C99 support, GCC and Clang are the closest. Microsoft does not support C99, and only focuses on C++ (which overlaps with C99 in places).

Answer (score 10):

You might have a problem compiling C code with a C++ compiler unless you explicitly restrict the compiler to use C (which all the C++ compilers know how to do). If the compiler uses C++ to compile C code you might have issues if in the C code you use words that are reserved in C++.

For example, C code like this:

```
int main(void) { int class = 5; return class;}
```

Will compile fine with a C compiler (or C++ compiler in C mode), but will not compile with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 6):

The two problems that I can quickly think of (there's probably more) that would arise when compiling C code with C++ is casting and variable names. For example:

```
char* new = malloc(20);
```

The above is valid C, but when compiling in C++ you would get the following errors:

1. `char*` cannot be assigned to `void*` without an explicit cast.
2. `new` is a keyword.

---

Yes, *some* compilers do support C99. GCC probably does, but I only have experience using MSVC and they don't support it.