# error C3861: 'initNode': identifier not found

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I am getting below compilation error:

> error C3861: 'initNode': identifier not found"

Below is the code:

```
# include <conio.h>
# include "stdafx.h"
# include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    node * next;
    int nodeValue;

};

node*createList (int value)  /*Creates a Linked-List*/
{
    node *dummy_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof (node));
    dummy_node->next=NULL;
    dummy_node->nodeValue = value;
    return dummy_node;
}


void addFront (node *head, int num ) /*Adds node to the front of Linked-List*/
{
    node*newNode = initNode(num);   
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head->next=newNode;
    newNode->nodeValue=num;
}

void deleteFront(node*num)   /*Deletes the value of the node from the front*/
{
    node*temp1=num->next;

    if (temp1== NULL) 
    {
        printf("List is EMPTY!!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        num->next=temp1->next;
        free(temp1);
    }

}

void destroyList(node *list)    /*Frees the linked list*/
{
    node*temp;
    while (list->next!= NULL) 
    {
        temp=list;
        list=temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(list);
}

int getValue(node *list)    /*Returns the value of the list*/
{
    return((list->next)->nodeValue);
}


void printList(node *list)   /*Prints the Linked-List*/
{

    node*currentPosition;
    for (currentPosition=list->next; currentPosition->next!=NULL; currentPosition=currentPosition->next)  
    {`enter code here`
        printf("%d \n",currentPosition->nodeValue);
    }   
    printf("%d \n",currentPosition->nodeValue);

}

node*initNode(int number) /*Creates a node*/
{
    node*newNode=(node*) malloc(sizeof (node));
    newNode->nodeValue=number;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    return(newNode);
}
```

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because `initNode()` is not visible before it is called.
To correct place a declaration for `initNode()`, or move its definition, to before its first use.

---

The code looks like C but it appears you are using a C++ compiler to compile it (as use of `node` and not `struct node` appears to not be causing the compiler to fail, unless you have not reported these errors in your post). If you use a C compiler (which can be easily achieved by having a `.c` extension on your source file with Visual Studio), you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc()`. See [Incompatibilities Between 
ISO C and ISO C++](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) , a link a found provided on answer to the question [What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler)

Comment: I put signature of all funtion at top but now this error is coming
"fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation"

Comment: @OOkhan, Don't put it before `struct node`.

Comment: Solve
but another error :(
"fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Comment: If the file you posted is a header file you should move the definitions into the `.c` file and keep declarations in the `.h` file. The question you posted has been answered OOkhan, you would be better to post a new question with the new problem. More people will see it and it much easier to provide a complete answer as an answer and not as comment.

Comment: the file i posted is not Header file. it's .cpp file and i am calling these function in another .cpp file.
And ok i am going to post my question.