# Compile as C source file as C++ using MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation

I'm working on C++ project. Because of some errors I got recommendation to set `Properties` > `C/C++` > `Advanced` > `Compile As` **and check** `Compile as C++ Code(/TP)`.

My project includes iniparser.c that has extension "C". What I want to know is whether my new settings (C++) can affect the compilation of my project, given that it contains a .c file (iniparser.c)?

Comment: Since the answer is yes (see below), I would recommend not to follow the recommendation, but to fix the error you see when not using /TP.

Comment: Also see [/Tc, /Tp, /TC, /TP (Specify Source File Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be a possible duplicate of this one:

[What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler)

Without knowing the details of your problem, there a number of issues that have to be considered when compiling C code with a C++ compiler. See this link for more details: http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm