# How to access an std::string member of C++ struct in C code

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have mixed C++ and C code. Inside the C++ code, I have a struct in `my_cpp_code.h`:

```cpp
typedef struct {
    std::string some_string;
    int some_int;
    bool some_bool;
} CppStruct;
```

Having another source file, say C `my_c_code.c`. Is it possible to access the `some_string` member of the struct in this file as a `const char *`?

Comment: No, that's not possible. C has no notion of class types.

Comment: you can adding a function in c++ code returning its c_str(), but that value is volatile ...

Comment: @bruno: Perhaps the evolution could be 1) your comment, 2) my answer, 3) your detailed answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba you are enough great/good to make a perfect answer :-)

Comment: @bruno: Oh you're so nice ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A C compiler wouldn't understand the definition of `CppStruct`. So no, it is not possible for a C program to access `CppStruct::some_string`. **But** you can provide a set of C++ functions exposing a C-compatible signature to read/write from/to `CppStruct::some_string`.

```
// === compat.h ===
struct CppStruct;
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    CppStruct* get_the_damn_struct();
    int set_some_string(CppStruct*, char* data, size_t len);
    int get_some_string(CppStruct*, char* data, size_t* len);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// === compat.cpp ===
// Implementation

// === c_program.c ===
#include <compat.h>

// usage (e.g.:
CppStruct* wrapper = get_the_damn_struct();
char* data = "Hello, World!";
if (0 != set_some_string(wrapper, data, strlen(data)) {
    // error handling
}
//)
```

Comment: If you don't typedef the initial struct you can use a forwarding defintion of the struct in the C header and pass a struct <namehere>* to the functions. so you don't need to cast in the Cpp Code and you don't get any issues when including both the C header and the C++ header. But this is a matter of taste.
C++ header: `struct CppStruct { std::string some_string; };`
C header: `struct CppStruct; int get_some_string(struct CppStruct*, char* data, size_t len); `

Answer (score 3):

Not directly no.

One solution would be to have an opaque pointer on the C language side (a bit like `FILE*`), that you pass to a function which is implemented on the C++ side (and is compiled with C linkage: consult your compiler documentation on how to do that). That function can have a `const char*` return type since both C and C++ understand that. That function can then `reintepret_cast` that opaque pointer (`p`, say) to an instance of your `struct`, then return `p->some_string.c_str()` back.

Comment: @bruno: Sorry wasn't clear enough. Indeed a `const char*` is the `return` type.

Answer (score 2):

You can have one C++ function that returns a pointer to such a struct-object, yet as `void*`, and you can have another C++ function that takes such a `void*`-pointer to a struct object and - after having casted it back - accesses the member's `c_str`-function. Declare these functions a pure C-functions in a separate header file (not mixed with C++ code):

Example:

```
// my_cpp_bridge.h:
void* getAStructPtr();
const char* getStringMemberPtr(void* structPtr);

// my_cpp_bridge.cpp:
#include "my_cpp_code.h"
#include "my_cpp_bridge.h"
void* getAStructPtr() {
   static CppStruct someSample;
   someSample.some_string = "Hello world!";
   return (void*)&someSample;
}
const char* getStringMemberPtr(void* structPtr) {
   const CppStruct *structPtr = reinterpret_cast<CppStruct*>(structPtr);
   return structPtr->c_str();
}

// my_test.c:
#include "my_cpp_bridge.h"
int main() {
   void* s = getAStructPtr();
   const char* content = s->getStringMemberPtr();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be an "XY problem" (you ask question 'X' but really you'd do better to ask 'Y' if only you knew it might be a better option). This answer poses an alternative that technically doesn't answer the question that you asked, but it can solve the problem that prompted the question:

### Compile your legacy C code as C++ and this isn't even an issue.

If you must keep your C code pure C, then any of the other answers are what you're looking for. But if, like me, you're working on a project that uses legacy C code mixed with new C++ code, then perhaps you should start moving the legacy code away from pure C. Of course if you need to keep the legacy code "pure C" because it's shared with a separate project that's still compiled as strict C then this isn't an option, but let's suppose that's not a requirement. I've done this twice now on two large firmware projects with excellent results.

If you compile your C code as C++, then you can start to take advantage of C++ features even in your legacy "C" code. One way to do that is to find a compiler option to treat C as C++ code; e.g. Visual Studio's /TP option (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785346/compile-as-c-source-file-as-c-using-msvc) for more info). For GCC, change your makefile to use g++. Or, if there is no such option, rename your .c files with .cpp extensions.

Once you're compiling C code as C++, you may run into other minor problems, but those shouldn't be too difficult to work through, and the long-term benefits will outweigh the initial hassle. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler) for more information about that. Perhaps the main issue is that if you use malloc(), you will need to typecast the return value before assigning it to a typed pointer.

Once you're compiling your legacy code as C++, then you can do everything in your legacy code that you can do in your new C++ code, so the issue posed by your original question is no longer an issue at all. You `#include <string>` in your C file and then just call `myCppStruct.some_string.c_str()` any time you need a raw `const char*` pointer (e.g. to call other legacy C functions that take `const char*` parameters). No need for a utility function to do it for you.

Comment: "_I can't imagine why some coward would downvote without providing any feedback_" this is a shared and recurrent  problem ^^ I am not one of the down voters, but probably you received DV because you are out of subject. The OP ask "how to mix C and C++" and you answer "do not mix and do only C++" ;-)

Comment: @bruno I guess I figured this might be an "XY problem" (OP asks 'X' but if they knew better they'd ask a different question, 'Y'). My answer is an alternative that technically doesn't answer the question that was asked, but it can solve the problem that prompted the question.

Comment: I think this is a valuable contribution to the discussion and perfectly fine to point this out since it offers an alternative solution under some circumstances. I don't get the down votes either, especially since your answer is quite comprehensive and well motivated. Thanks for writing this down!