# C++ cannot find cmath

Tags: c++, glm-math

When I try to build a `C` project in code:blocks on ubuntu 14.04 that uses GLM I get this

> **fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory**

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Install C++ compiler support.

Comment: ***C And C++ Arent the same thing***

Comment: Why are you building a C Project.. your suppose to build a C++ Project , for cmath . look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) for more reference.

Comment: C is not C++. Different languages behave differently. You seem to want a C++ project.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you are building a `C` project in Code::Blocks. It gives you the error:

> fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory

because you are supposed to be building a C++ project, but the header `<cmath>` is only available for `C++`, not `C`. Look [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) for more references

Comment: That is true. However, when I go to settings > compiler > toolchain executables, it shows GCC for C and G++ for C++

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb yes so use `G++` For `C++` .. `G++` Is a Compiler for `C++` while `GCC` Is a compiler for `C`

Comment: Also the part that includes cmath is part of an entirely different c++ library (GLM)

Comment: I was under the impression that it would automatically compile C with GCC and C++ with g++. Also I though c++ was backwards compatible

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb backward compatible? If you mean "I thought C++ Can compile C Programs" , Absolutely not! There are cases for which there is valid C Code and Invalid C++ Code.

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb GCC will only compile a file in C++ if the extension is `.cc` or `.cpp`, or you specify it with `-x` or `-std`. You can also use g++ which defaults to C++ instead of C

Comment: I mean they are pretty much the same language. Isn't valid C guaranteed to work when compiled with G++?

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb **No, not at all!** see [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler).

Comment: @firstnamegklsodascb: This has been discussed a hundred times here and elsewhere already. Do research on your own and feel free where C allows something like `const int i = 10; static int a[i];` or C++ `auto int i = 10, a[i];`. **for example**. And gcc is not the actual compiler, but front end only. It also calls the assembler, linker, etc. depending on the arguments..