# How common is it to mix C with C++?

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

I wanted to know how widely used is the mixing of C++ and C. I mean as in using of C libraries/functions and call it in C++ program like how it is done here [Mix C with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code). How extensive is its use in real world? Is it rarely used, avoided mostly or pretty common? Anybody can shed some lights on it??

Comment: Technically its ubiquitous.  Both Windows and *nix use a C API for interacting with the OS.

Comment: A significant number of libraries is written in C. You don't want to miss on them to maintain the "C++ purity".

Comment: Implementations of the C++ standard library itself will often [mix C libraries](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring).  It's not required, but it's a fairly easy way to implement "things from C".

Comment: Even when writing mostly C++ projects (targeting windows) I very often have at least a few C files, mostly tool generated but not always.

Comment: If I am not wrong, pretty much the whole Arduino/microcontroller programming situation is like that

Comment: Since C++ was originally introduced as an extended or enhanced C, a lot of C programmers claimed they were C++ programmers, based on using techniques from C and a few C++ features.    Quite a few courses still teach C++ that way.  So a lot of programmers write code that is mostly C but using a few specific features of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly common. You can either

- <strike>compile the C stuff with C++ compiler without any issues</strike>  OK, others noted that this is definitely not true: [What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler)

or

- use both object files, static and dynamic libraries compiled with C compiler but then you should be aware of name mangling that C++ compiler does and the C compiler does not (due to the fact that C does not allow name overloading but C++ does). In such case there is `extern "C"` linker directive to use C linkage, i.e. does not mangle names that has been compiled with C compiler.

For good explanation how to use C linkage in C++, refer e.g. to this answer here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/12118546

This is the reason you often see code like this

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// all of your legacy C code here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Sample from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994075/12118546

Cryptic linker errors like these would result if you would forget about this:

```
...
/home/AbiSfw/ccvvuHoX.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `foo()'
...
```

Sample from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573818/12118546

Comment: You're likely to get quite a few compilation errors when compiling C code as C++, unless the C code was written with this in mind. It's rare to do this in my experience.

Comment: *compile the C stuff with C++ compiler without any issues* This is bound to end in tears.

Comment: @interjay Those would be linker error, but I am not going to be a nitpicker here. I will add that to my answer as I was quite a confused when I have seen those for the first time.

Comment: I'm talking about compiler errors, not linker errors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler

Comment: Yay, I see now... Allright, adding these notes.